# Inserting 100,000 rows at a time .. error identity column violation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to insert row by row in a table about 100k records.. I get this error after some 140 or so..

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK_table1'. Cannot insert duplicate
>   key in object 'table1'.  The statement
>   has been terminated.

In this case the primary key is an IDENTITY column. I do not include that column in my INSERT statements.

I ran `DBCC CHECKIDENT (table1,noreseed)`

The current identity value and the current column value are NOT the same.

If I run the same command in 5 min, they become the same.

I cannot figure out what the problem is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what's your database server?  What's your insert statement?  Also, your period key seems stuck down.

Comment: DB server is SQL server 2000. insert into tableA (cola,colb) select (cola, colb) from tableb.. and there is one more column in TableA which is identity column.. and I'm not trying to insert that.. what is Period Key?

Comment: And the table is destination table is empty when you do the insert?

Comment: No.. destination table has already 125million records.. and the identity column data type is bigint.

Answer (score 1):

If the destination table is not empty then you want to reseed the identity column to the next highest existing value like so:

```
Declare @Max bigint
Set @Max = ( Select Max(IdCol) From TableA ) + 1
DBCC CHECKIDENT( TableA, RESEED, @Max )
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your reply..couple of questions.. first question is .. why is there a differnce when I first ran this 
DBCC CHECKIDENT (table1,noreseed)
the current identity value and the currnt column are not same.. 
but after 5 minute when I ran again .. they both are same.. Any idea?
Second question.. If I reseed the value.. Hope nothing changes for the existing rows right? It's just that we are going to have new seed value when we insert the next new row? Correct?

Comment: NORESEED simply states that the identity seed should not be changed. Using RESEED you are forcing a new starting value for new identity values. To answer you second question: correct. It will simply start rows at a new value.

Comment: I haven't executed this solution but I was thinking about this.. 
When I executed DBCC CHECKIDENT (table1,noreseed) I got the number for example 4000 but when I exucted select max(IdCol) from tableA
I got a number  3500 which is less than 4000.
This sounds right to me because It could have happened that there are some rows deleted with index 3500 to 4000. 
First thing is Why am i getting this error? because the next row im giong to insert will have the idcol values as 4000+1.. so why am i getting this number.. even if the new idcol value is going to be max(idcol)+1 then its  (cont.,)

Comment: 3500+1.. so why am i getting this error in first place.. 

second how reseeding the value to start from 3500+1 is going to help me?

Comment: The error is that the identity generator is trying to create a value that is already in the table. That means starting at 3500 on, at some point it hits a duplicate. Thus the idea of finding the highest value used and reseeding the identity column. Is this table getting values while you are trying to do this insert? Are there triggers on the table?

Comment: I tried this no luck.. I still get the same error. There are no triggers in the DB..

Comment: Just to confirm: No triggers. No other traffic to the table. Identity reseeded to one higher than the highest value in the table. Not inserting into the identity column directly. All of this and it still does not work? Try inserting into a temp table with an identity column seeded exactly like you reseeded the main table and then compare the values in the temp table with those in the main table. That will show you the duplicates and might illuminate where you were getting the collisions.

Comment: Something that should have occurred to me earlier, how can you have an identity seed of 3500 on table with 125 million rows? You reseeded the destination table not the source table?

Comment: I gave 3500 as an example. The max value was something around 124million i reseed the value to 124million+1..

Also I tried this but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bcp command for this work. You can specify that identity being checked or not.